# Inserting options to a Multi-Select product attribute in Magento 2 Programatically

Tags: magento2

I have figured out how to create an InstallData.php script for adding a custom multiselect product attribute as part of a custom module in Magento 2, but I'm not finding any examples of how I could also create some initial option values for the new attribute.

Does anyone have any examples of how to add options to my attribute in the InstallData.php script?

Answer (score 5):

I dug around in the Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup class and found my solution. Turns out you can supply an `option` key containing values you want to have created when adding a new attribute.

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'my_custom_attribute_code',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'required' => false,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'filterable_in_search' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'group' => 'General',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'option' => [
                'values' => [
                    'Left',
                    'Right',
                    'Up',
                    'Down',
                    'All'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Hey @Johnson, I have issue with multi-select attribute when i set is_user_define 0 attribute save time to give me js error..like as /magento216/pub/static/version1496830481/adminhtml/Magento/b‌​ackend/en_US/mage/ba‌​ckend/validation.js:‌​205 Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function

Comment: Also, FIY magneto default attribute in multiselect type text and is_user_define is 0 give the same error.